# Split text into words ignoring the single quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use javascript's regexp to get the words out of a text but contractions should be seen as single words: "can't" should stay "can't" not "can" and "t".

I tried this:

```
var text = "I'd like to make it work."
var words = text.match(/\w+/g);
```

But it doesn't work properly on " I'd ".

How to make it treat words with the single quote as a single word, but not two words ?

Comment: `var words = text.match(/[A-Za-z0-9_\']+/g);`

Comment: Try this regex `/[\w']+/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = "I'd like to make it work."
var words = text.split(' ');
```

returns ["I'd", "like", "to", "make", "it", "work."]

**EDITED**

I'm sorry, ChiChou was right in his comment

```
var words = text.match(/[A-Za-z0-9_\']+/g);
```

It works like expected

Comment: work. is not a word. You need to remove/ignore punctuation too

Comment: sorry, I see my mistake

Comment: How about `words = text.replace(/[,.?!]/g,"").split(" ")`

Comment: You should type all separatind sings if you whant to use your replace. But ChiChou regex includes them all

Comment: A-Za-z - this part of regex is depend on language

Comment: I know, So I do not use it

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be a negated match. You can add what you don't want to match inside of the character class. The caret `^` inside of a character class `[]` in considered the negation operator.

```
var text = "I'd like to make it work."
var words = text.match(/[^\s?!.]+/g);
console.log(words); // => [ 'I'd', 'like', 'to', 'make', 'it', 'work' ]
```

Regular expression:

```
[^\s?!.]+     any character except: whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), 
              '?', '!', '.' (1 or more times)
```

Comment: +1 and also I suggest adding `"` to the list in your negated character class. The result would successfully extract almost all words from typical texts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match domains and other word-like objects that are dot rather than hyphen delimited, you can modify @hwnd's solution as follows:

```
text.match(/[^*"\s?!\(\)]*[^*"\s?!.,\(\)]/g);
```

Periods (e.g., at the end of a sentence) won't be included in words, but words such as domains like stackoverflow.com that contain dots within them will be returned as a single word.

Double quotes are automatically ignored. Single quotes could also be ignored, but only by losing the ability to recognize words like 'Tis (as in *'Tis so sweet to trust in Jesus...*) or possessives like *students'*. Perfectly parsing all words requires a bit of comprehension beyond a regular expression's capabilities, but either one of these solutions will do the job rather well in most cases.

The following regular expression works even better for English, except since JavaScript doesn't support locale for `\w`, I would be careful using it in any potentially internationalized contexts.

```
/[^\s!"<>\(\)\[\]\{\}?`]*[\w']/g
```

(For example, it recognizes every word in this answer properly, except for "e.g." on which it mistakenly thinks the trailing `.` is a period and ignores it.)

This final RE will work in any language just as well:

```
[^\s!"<>\(\)\[\]\{\}?`]*[^\s!"<>\(\)\[\]\{\}?`.,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
/[\w']*[^\d\W]/g
```